# Parse an PSObject instance to a C# object

Tags: c#, powershell, psobject

How can I parse an PSObject instance to a C# [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) model entity?

The PSObject instance is a dynamic object that contains these properties:

```
@{Name=David;  Diff=0.0268161397964839; File=Output.txt}
```

I have C# POCO model that fits those fields.

Is there a nice way to cast?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You either need to convert the `PSObject` instance to some common representation or iterate over `PSObject.Properties` and fill the fields of the POCO using reflection.

This simple serialize-deserialize code with Newtosoft.Json implements the first way and may work well for simple cases:

```
public class MyInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Diff { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PSObject obj = PSObject.AsPSObject(new { Name = "David", Diff = 0.2, File = "output.txt" });

    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj.Properties.ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value));
    Console.WriteLine(serialized);

    var deseialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyInfo>(serialized);
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {deseialized.Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Diff: {deseialized.Diff}");
    Console.WriteLine($"File: {deseialized.File}");
}
```

Output:

```
{"Name":"David","Diff":0.2,"File":"output.txt"}
Name: David
Diff: 0,2
File: output.txt
```

Comment: ad circular ref with NewtonSoft.. I will give it another try.